# Python sort is not working appropriately

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am trying to sort a list in python by one of it's property, however, it's not sorted correctly, any hint.

I try to print the value before and after sort, they are printing the same value.

```
 def kmeans_clustering(cluster_list, num_clusters, num_iterations):
    """
    Compute the k-means clustering of a set of clusters

    Input: List of clusters, number of clusters, number of iterations
    Output: List of clusters whose length is num_clusters
    """

    # initialize k-means clusters to be initial clusters with largest populations
    for idx in range(len(cluster_list)):
        print cluster_list[idx].total_population()

    print "sort.."
    sorted(cluster_list, key = lambda x: x.total_population(), reverse = True)

    for idx in range(len(cluster_list)):
        print cluster_list[idx].total_population()
```

Comment: Sorted returns the list, sorted, it does not actually mutate the object. Try cluster_list = sorted(cluster_list... and see if that works

Comment: Never iterate over an index range unless you need the index for another purpose. `for cluster in cluster_list` is clearer and more concise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a new sorted list, and does not sort the list in-place.

```
>>> x = [3, 2, 1]
>>> sorted(x)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x
[3, 2, 1]
```

If you want to sort in-place, use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) instead:

```
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Side note:

Instead of using the index to access each element, just iterate the list:

```
for cluster in cluster_list:
    print cluster.total_population()
```